# Javascript Support Second Life's Web Browser

Tags: javascript, linden-scripting-language

I'm looking for information on javascript support for the inbuilt Web Browser. The wiki doesn't have any information, and on my sites jquery based code doesn't work. However it runs the Sunspider benchmark just fine, so js must be supported in some way.

[Second Life Wiki - Web Browser](http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/Web_Browser)

[Sunspider results](http://bit.ly/8vrUyD)

Anyone can point me to a good resource? thanks

Comment: I thought it embed Mozilla browser ... and Mozilla browser supports standard javascript !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial version of the Web content rendering library in Second Life used the Mozilla/Gecko rendering engine. This is now deprecated.

Second Life now uses LLQtWebKit.

A Media Plugin API to render Web content in the Second Life viewer is now available as well.

- http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/LLQtWebKit
- http://wiki.secondlife.com/wiki/User:Becky_Pippen/Shared_Media_LSL_Recipes#Calling_external_JavaScript_functions_.28JQuery_example.29

Answer (score 1):

Okay after a deep investigation my conclusion is as follows:

```
* Media Browser works ok with javascript
* Media Browser works ok with jquery
* Media Browser works ok with jquery served from another domain
* My issue: Media Browser cannot deal with the microsoft cdn version of jquery (<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>)
```

Regular desktop browsers work with all of the above (including firefox, ie, chrome). Therefore I recommend if you do want to use this use the google Ajax Library API at http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlibs/documentation/

I'd still like to see documentation, a script console and debugger for the media browser however.